# TemplateURL provided in angular js routes isn't loading the required file when getting response from node

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to fetch data from mysql using node(routes.js) and wanted the result to be injected in club.html ,file which is dynamically updated in index.html using ng-view. But when i try this scenario i see the node response (i.e json containing results) is directly getting displayed on browser rather than injecting to club.html then displaying

Below are following files:

appRoutes.js --> for routing on angular side

clubCtrl.js --> club controller

clubService.js --> club service to fill data from node

Routes.js --> partial sample of retriving data from database and sending response

club.html --> partial club view file

index.html --> file on which club.html will get dynamically displayed using ng-view.

app.js -> injecting all modules

```
**appRoutes.js**   
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider',  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })

        // nerds page that will use the NerdController
        .when('/club', {
            templateUrl: 'views/club.html',
            controller: 'ClubController'
        }); 

}]);


**ClubCtrl.js**

angular.module('ClubCtrl', []).controller('ClubController', [ '$http','Club', function($http, Club) {
    var club = this;
    club.data = {};
    Club.getClubData().then(function(response){
        club.data = response.data;
    });
}]);

**ClubService.js**
angular.module('ClubService', []).factory('Club', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        getClubData : function() {
            return $http.get('/club');
        }
      };


}]);

**Routes.js**
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            console.log("routes send get(*)");
            res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html')); // load our public/index.html file
        });
    app.get('/club', function(req, res){
        console.log("routes send get /club");
    con.query("select * from club_data", function(err, rows,field) {
    if (!err)
    {
        console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
        res.json(rows);
    }
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query. ', err);
        });
    });

};

**Club.html**
    </div>
          <div class="row " >
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 image-feature" ng-repeat='dat in main.data'>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src="images/club/{{dat.imagename}}"alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{ dat.name }}</h3>
                        <p>{{dat.desccription}}</p>
                        <p>{{dat.date}}</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">I'm Going!</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


**index.html**
<body ng-app="staygala" ng-controller="MainController">

    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

**app.js**
angular.module('staygala', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl', 'ClubCtrl', 'ClubService']);
```

Comment: Change your route from /club to /api/club in node side and call it like return $http.get('/api/club'); because when you call your page in the browser with /club. node server catches it and renders the json as response.

Comment: this doesnot work. I am getting Connection established `GET /club 404 12.481 ms - 17 `as node output and `Cannot Get /club in browser`

Comment: also get /club is called through home.html via hyperlink with href = '/club'

Comment: you should use ng-href

Comment: i am using ng-href only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using same port.

Change your route from /club to /api/club in nodejs side route and call it like return `$http.get('/api/club');` in angular service i.e in ClubService.js because when you call your page in the browser with /club. node server catches it and renders the json as response.

so here is the change you have to make :

in Routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            console.log("routes send get(*)");
            res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html')); // load our public/index.html file
        });
    app.get('/api/club', function(req, res){
        console.log("routes send get /club");
    con.query("select * from club_data", function(err, rows,field) {
    if (!err)
    {
        console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
        res.json(rows);
    }
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query. ', err);
        });
    });

};
```

and in ClubService.js

```
angular.module('ClubService', []).factory('Club', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        getClubData : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/club');
        }
      };


}]);
```

One more thing you are using main.data in ng-repeat in view club.html but i am not able to see controllerAs in route so you have to add controllerAs in angular club route or change model in controller.

Comment: this doesnot work. I am getting `Connection established
GET /club 404 12.481 ms - 17` as node output and `Cannot Get /club` in browser.

Comment: past here full url of /club what you are trying

Comment: `<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="about-item scrollpoint sp-effect2">
                            <a ng-href="/club" style="text-decoration:none">
                            <div class = 'img-hover'>
                            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" style="width:200px;height:200px;" src ="images/freeze/Party-1.png">
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>`

Comment: this is calling to node server. your node server will be listing to 8081 port. Angular is ajax based single app so url should be like http://127.0.0.1:8081/#/club

Comment: angular js app will have url with #

Comment: so should i change ng-href to #/club instead of /club?

Comment: thanks that solves the issue, but now when i press back button i cannt see main content only <header></header> and <footer></footer> is displayed rest all blank

Comment: now when i press back button i cannt see main content only <header></header> and <footer></footer> is displayed rest all blank  or more like main content is hiding behind something blank. I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'restart' of undefined on pressing back` in console